# How can I use less memory for a large dataset of images? (Python - Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm new to deep learning. I'm trying to train a model that identifies plant diseases, and I'm using [this](https://www.kaggle.com/abdallahalidev/plantvillage-dataset) dataset that has a bunch of images. I'm aware that this is a lot of data, and I'm only using the `color` subfolder. I want to use all of the data in that subfolder. The thing is, **Kaggle** only provides 13GB of memory as of now, and my session keeps restarting because my script is trying to use more memory than it has. Here is my code:

```
### There are some imports here that I removed because there is a lot of them

NUM_CLASSES = 38
IMG_SIZE = 150

x = []
y = []

def train_data_gen(DIR, ID):
    for img in os.listdir(DIR):
        try:
            path = DIR + '/' + img
            img = plt.imread(path)
            img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
            if img.shape == (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3):
                x.append(img)
                y.append(ID)
        except:
            None
#--
for DIR in os.listdir('../input/plantvillage-dataset/color/'):
    train_data_gen('../input/plantvillage-dataset/color/' + DIR, DIR)
    print(DIR)
#
print('reached label encoder')
le = LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(y)
x = np.array(x)
y = to_categorical(y, NUM_CLASSES)

print('data split')
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.15)
x_train,x_val,y_train,y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size = 0.15)

print('datagen')
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=False,
    samplewise_center=False,
    samplewise_std_normalization=False,
    rotation_range=60,
    zoom_range = 0.1,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=0.1,
    fill_mode = "reflect"
)
print('datagen_fit')
datagen.fit(x_train)

print('model')
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding='Same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding='Same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
#model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding='Same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
#model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding='Same', activation='relu'))
#model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))

print('Model compile')
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Model Fit')
model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train,y_train,batch_size=32), epochs=75, steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0]//32, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), verbose=1)

model.save('plantus_model')
```

I've placed print functions through out my code to see where the actual problem is. The part where it stops is right when I fit `datagen`. I don't think it's that one thing that uses up so much ram, but all the stuff before it too. How can I reduce RAM usage so I can actually get to training my model?
Thank you in advance for providing answers and constructive feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using datagen.fit. This is only necessary if you are setting any of the parameters `featurewise_center`, `samplewise_center`, `featurewise_std_normalization`,
`samplewise_std_normalization` or `zca_whitening` to `True`. Since you are not doing that you do not need to fit the data set. This should avoid you using to much memory.